# .htaccess regex to find the last occurence for a match

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am trying to get the last occurrence of a particular match in a url, this is the line I currently have `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+/?)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]`.

So for example the following url `/first-part/second-part/` needs to return a get variable of p='second-part' whereas `/first-part/` needs to return a variable of p='first-part'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get what you want quite easily by removing the caret - you *don't* want the pattern to match from the start to the end, but just near the end:

```
([a-zA-Z[0-9\-.]+/?)$
```

Example: http://rubular.com/r/TQcppGpoq4

You may also want to remove the `[` character, it looks like a mistake.
You can simplify the pattern to: `([\w\-.]+/?)$`.

Comment: And that works, although for some reason I can't figure, removing the caret stops the styles loading? In fact stops any resources loading?

Comment: @kalpaitch - That is a very broad rule, which will **match almost all urls in your site** (as long as they're made of ascii letters). This was the case for the original pattern as well... Really, what is the difference between `/first-part/second-part/` and `/style-lib/main-style.css` ? You should create a more specific rule...

Comment: Of course, of course. Its always takes a while to get those cogs moving. Cheers